# I am confused why my program is not looping and printing

Tags: java, oop, loops

The program just outputs the song ninety nine bottles of beer on the wall. It compiles with no errors, but nothing happens in my code. I think that it has something to do with how I am setting up my parameters for the last two methods, and my instance variables but I am having some trouble understanding this.

```
package beersong;

public class BeerSong

{
    private int numBeerBottles;
    private String numberInWords;
    private String secondNumberInWords;
    private int n;

    private String[] numbers = {"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", 
        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
        "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
    };

    private String[] tens = {"", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty",
        "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" 
    };

    //constructor
    public BeerSong (int numBeerBottles)
    {
        this.numBeerBottles = numBeerBottles;
    }

    //method to return each line of song
    public String convertNumberToWord(int n)
    {
        if(n<20)
        {
            this.numberInWords = numbers[n];
        }

        else if (n%10 == 0)
        {
            this.numberInWords = tens[n/10];
        }

        else 
        {
            this.numberInWords = (tens[(n - n%10)] + numbers[n%10]);
        }

        return this.numberInWords;
    }

    //method to get word for n-1 beer in song
    public String getSecondBeer(int n)
    {
        if((n-1)<20)
        {
            this.secondNumberInWords = numbers[(n-1)];
        }

        else if ((n-1)%10 == 0)
        {
            this.secondNumberInWords = tens[(n-1)/10];
        }

        else
        {
            this.secondNumberInWords = (tens[((n-1) - (n-1)%10)] + numbers[(n-1)%10]);
        }
        return this.secondNumberInWords;
    }

    //method to actually print song to screen
    public void printSong()
    {
        for (n=numBeerBottles; n==0; n--)
        {
        System.out.println(convertNumberToWord(n) + " bottles of beer on the "
                + "wall. " + convertNumberToWord(n) + " bottles of beer. "
                + "You take one down, pass it around "
                + getSecondBeer(n) + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BeerSong newsong = new BeerSong(99);
        newsong.printSong();
    }
}
```

Comment: n == 0 must be n >= 0 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop condition is unlikely to be true when it's first run:

```
for(n=numBeerBottles; n==0; n--)
```

That says, in order for the loop to be executed, **`n` must be `0`.**  That doesn't seem correct, given you're reciting "N bottles of beer on the wall".

What you're intending to write is that `n` must be greater than or equal to 0.

```
for(n = numBeerBottles; n >= 0; n--)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you `for-loop` is setup incorrectly...

```
for (n=numBeerBottles; n==0; n--)
```

It is basically saying, for `n = numBeerBottles`, while `n == 0` do `n--`...

Try...

```
for (n=numBeerBottles; n >= 0; n--)
```

instead...

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case a while loop is more intuitive and the verb suits what you would say in English

```
n = numBeerBottles;
while (n >= 0) 
{
// code
   n--;
 }
```